# Stripe: Get card information so customer can update their card

Tags: stripe-payments

My app uses subscriptions with Stripe.

I want to create a standard "account" page, which will list the customer's current card information (like "MasterCard" and last 4 of card number), and give the customer the option of updating that information.

I'm stuck on the first piece--getting back the current card information. To do this, I need the current card_id. I have tried the "listSources" method, but this returns blank data where the card info is supposed to be. What do I need to do to get that card info?

**Here is what I've tried:**

(I'm using Node, and running this server side)

The closest method I have found is [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list):

```
var stripe = require('stripe')(STRIPE_TOKEN);

stripe.customers.listSources(
  CUSTOMER_ID,
  {object: 'bank_account', limit: 3},
  function(err, cards) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);
```

This returns information (there's no error), but the docs say this method should return a data array of the cards that includes the card id for each. In testing, the data array keeps coming back empty.

I am testing with a customer id that has a valid subscription and a card that I can see on my Stripe dashboard.

Why is the data array coming back empty?

Note: there's also a [retrieve source method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/retrieve), which should give back card details, but this method requires you have the id of the card you want info on, and that's what I am not able to get right now.

Comment: Are you sure your app uses cards/sources and not the newer [PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) Stripe is moving towards? If you wrote your integration recently, it's likely you're using the newer API.

Comment: That's really helpful. I think that is indeed the issue. When I run the stripe.paymentMethods.list... it returns info about the payment methods, including card type and last 4 of the number. So I'm guessing this is what I need to use. Thanks!

Comment: To update the card the customer is charged on, is the best practice to use the 'stripe.paymentMethods.update' function?

Comment: You can only update address and expiration date on a PaymentMethod. A different card number should be handled via a *new* PaymentMethod record.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I can use the "paymentsMethods.list" method to show the payment methods (most recent entered appear first, I assume--so that would be the card I show), and then, if customer clicks a "change billing method" button, then I get their new details and run the paymentMethods.create function.

Comment: Precisely, yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup><sub>Converting this to an answer...</sub></sup>

Stripe has recently rolled out [PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods), which replace (and are separate from) the older Tokens and Sources API.

OP's issue is that their integration creates PaymentMethod objects, which won't show up in the sources list, but can instead be accessed via `stripe.paymentMethods.list`.

Comment: I am able to display the card details correctly, and then able to have the customer enter new card information with Stripe elements. Then, it seems like I get a "new payment method" result using createPaymentMethod, described here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/create_payment_method

Comment: BUT, this does not seem to actually update the customer's card. On my stripe dashboard, the customer is not showing any new activity or any new card being created. I am also running the createPaymentMethod from the client side, which seems wrong--but if I try to run from server side, I am not sure how to pass along the card details gathered with elements (seems wrong to pass them in the url with a post call).

Comment: @9gt53wS https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach "To use this PaymentMethod as the default for invoice or subscription payments, set invoice_settings.default_payment_method, on the Customer to the PaymentMethod’s ID."

Comment: And yes, you should be making PMs client-side. You do not ever want the raw card details going to your server - that places you in PCI scope and that's a HUGE, expensive undertaking.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. BTW, what I meant by server side: I am not saving any payment info on my own server. Rather, I assumed I should be running the createPaymentMethod "server side"--meaning with a Lambda function. So I assumed I should run that method on Lambda, not directly from the client. But it's easier to do it from the client, so that is fine by me. I'll check it out.

Comment: Well, the `createPaymentMethod` option typically takes card details. The docs state for it "We strongly recommend using Stripe.js instead of interacting with this API directly." because of this PCI issue. You might also consider Stripe's Checkout tool for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205534/discussion-between-9gt53ws-and-ceejayoz).